# Problem with token code

Tags: contract-development, ether

I'm new in the Ethereum and programming languages at all I have a problem with this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8

contract MyToken { 
/* Public variables of the token */
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals;

/* This creates an array with all balances */
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
function MyToken(uint256 _supply, string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals) {
    /* if supply not given then generate 1 million of the smallest unit of the token */
    if (_supply == 0) _supply = 1000000;

    /* Unless you add other functions these variables will never change */
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _supply;
    name = _name;     
    symbol = _symbol;

    /* If you want a divisible token then add the amount of decimals the base unit has  */
    decimals = _decimals;
}

/* Send coins */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
    /* if the sender doenst have enough balance then stop */
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;
    if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;

    /* Add and subtract new balances */
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    /* Notifiy anyone listening that this transfer took place */
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
}
```

}

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `pragma solidity ^0.4.8` to `pragma solidity ^0.4.8;`